# Cuts in a simplicial complex embedded in Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $K$ be a finite $d$-dimensional simplicial complex embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. The setting of this question is simplicial homology with coefficients over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. By Alexander duality $K$ partitions $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ into $\beta_d + 1$ connected components, where $\beta_d$ is the $d$th Betti number of $K$. We define $G$ to be the dual graph of $K$. $G$ is the graph whose vertices are the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ and whose edges are the $d$-dimensional simplices of $K$. Two vertices are adjacent if and only if their corresponding connected components share a common $d$-simplex in the intersection of their boundaries.

It is easy to see that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $d$-dimensional cycles in $K$ and minimal edge cuts in $G$. This is analogous to cycle/cut duality in planar graphs.

What does a cycle in $G$ correspond to in $K$? My intuition is that it should be something analogous to a cut in a graph. In terms of homology a graph cut is a set of edges whose removal increases the rank of the zeroth homology group of the graph (because this homology group counts the number of connected components.)

Is the dual of a cycle in $G$ a set of $d$-dimensional simplices in $K$ whose removal increases the rank of the $(d-1)$th homology group? This seems likely to me, but I do not know how to prove it.